# Who owns a file handle in windows?

Tags: windows, file, handle

How do you discover which process has an open handle on a file?  Specifically, how do you do this programmaticly?

Comment: Given that he wants to know how to do this programmatically, this *is* programming-related and *doesn't* belong on server-fault.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an API for it, I don't know. If there is, it may an API in the kernel.

Another possibility (sorry to be vague, but I'm answering this now in case no-one else posts a better answer) is that there is no (documented) API, and that the programs which do it do so by using undocumented knowledge of the contents of the handle, and/or of the memory which the handle (when treated as a pointer) is pointing to: for example, I found [A Process' Kernel Object Handle Table](http://book.51cto.com/art/200808/87776.htm), and I think that that (people saying that they had reverse-engineered undocumented memory structures) is what I remember reading in the Softice manual years ago.

One place to look for more information might be [File System Filter Drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx).

Another (perhaps better) way might be to use `depends` or `dumpbin /imports` to try to see what APIs the relevent Sysinternals program is using.

Answer (score -1):

Process explorer from Sysinternals will tell you this.